Unity IAP issues with subscription data
Recently I tried to integrate the purchase of a subscription into my Unity project and encountered a problem with incorrect data on the Android platform, which the Unity library returns to me in App Purchase (I described the problem in more detail on the Unity portal). In short, the problem is related to updating the Google Play Billing Library to 7th version, which is why the methods used by In App Purchase are outdated, at least these are the conclusions that I came to as a result of my searches.
The only solution I came to was to try to integrate the Google Billing Library directly into the project, but I’m probably missing something and there is a more optimal solution to this problem, perhaps someone has already encountered a similar problem?
